# Trying to Find Variable in Databricks Apache Table Fails- Why?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, databricks

I am running Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12, and get this error:

**org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unable to fetch tables of db default**

... when trying to run this code:

```
  databaseName = "database"
  desiredColumn = "work_unit_code"
  database = spark.sql(f"show tables in {databaseName} ").collect()
  display(database)

  tablenames = []
  for row in database:
         cols = spark.table(row.tableName).columns
         **listColumns= spark.table(row.tableName).columns**
         if desiredColumn in listColumns:
              tablenames.append(row.tableName)
```

Does anyone know what's going on, please? Thanks in advance.

Trying to aggregate total columns within a specific database table, then iterate through columns to see if a specific variable exists there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `tableName` column contains just the table name, but not the database name.

Change `spark.table(row.tableName)` to the `spark.table(f"{databaseName}.{row.tableName})`